# R package installation is successful on all machines but one

Tags: macos, r, linker, compiler-errors, g++

We are a team working on an R package containing C/C++ code. The package can successfully be installed on all the machines but one. These all run the same version of Mac OS X. I have provided the log files for the installation of the package on my computer (success) and a colleague's computer (error). The package depends on the Rcpp package and the GSL library, both of which were successfully installed on both machines.

**My Computer**

```
WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME
* installing to library '/Users/dejayn/R/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0-library/2.15'
* installing *source* package 'mrenci' ...
** libs
*** arch - x86_64
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG -fopenmp -fopenmp -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/dejayn/R/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0-library/2.15/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64  -c MRMRTree.cc -o MRMRTree.o
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG -fopenmp -fopenmp -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/dejayn/R/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0-library/2.15/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64  -c Matrix.cc -o Matrix.o
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG -fopenmp -fopenmp -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/dejayn/R/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0-library/2.15/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64  -c MiMBuilder.cc -o MiMBuilder.o
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG -fopenmp -fopenmp -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/dejayn/R/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0-library/2.15/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64  -c SymmetricMatrix.cc -o SymmetricMatrix.o
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG -fopenmp -fopenmp -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/dejayn/R/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0-library/2.15/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64  -c adaptor.cc -o adaptor.o
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG -fopenmp -fopenmp -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/dejayn/R/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0-library/2.15/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64  -c memory.cc -o memory.o
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG -fopenmp -fopenmp -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/dejayn/R/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0-library/2.15/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64  -c tools.cc -o tools.o
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/opt/local/lib -o mrenci.so MRMRTree.o Matrix.o MiMBuilder.o SymmetricMatrix.o adaptor.o memory.o tools.o /Users/dejayn/R/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0-library/2.15/Rcpp/lib/x86_64/libRcpp.a -fopenmp -fopenmp -L/opt/local/lib/R/lib/x86_64 -lR
installing to /Users/dejayn/R/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0-library/2.15/mrenci/libs/x86_64
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** testing if installed package can be loaded

* DONE (mrenci)
```

**Colleague's Computer**

```
WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME
* installing to library '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library'
* installing *source* package 'mrenci' ...
** libs
*** arch - x86_64
g++ -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG  -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c MRMRTree.cc -o MRMRTree.o
MRMRTree.cc: In member function 'double* const MRMRTree::bootstrap(unsigned int)':
MRMRTree.cc:73: warning: iteration variable 'i' is unsigned
g++ -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG  -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c Matrix.cc -o Matrix.o
g++ -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG  -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c MiMBuilder.cc -o MiMBuilder.o
MiMBuilder.cc: In member function 'Matrix* const MiMBuilder::createMiM(unsigned int*, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int)':
MiMBuilder.cc:102: warning: iteration variable 'i' is unsigned
g++ -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG  -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c SymmetricMatrix.cc -o SymmetricMatrix.o
g++ -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG  -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c adaptor.cc -o adaptor.o
g++ -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG  -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c memory.cc -o memory.o
g++ -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 -DNDEBUG  -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c tools.cc -o tools.o
g++ -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -o mrenci.so MRMRTree.o Matrix.o MiMBuilder.o SymmetricMatrix.o adaptor.o memory.o tools.o /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rcpp/lib/x86_64/libRcpp.a -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/mrenci/libs/x86_64
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/mrenci/libs/x86_64/mrenci.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/mrenci/libs/x86_64/mrenci.so, 6): Symbol not found: _GOMP_critical_name_end
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/mrenci/libs/x86_64/mrenci.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/mrenci/libs/x86_64/mrenci.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/mrenci'
```

At first, the installation on my colleague's computer would result in the compilation of the package for both architectures, upon which g++ complained about an unknown `-arch` argument. This issue, however, appears to have been mitigated by forcing the targeting of a single architecture `x86_64`. It is also worth noting that as a result of these errors, all computers now have several versions of R and g++. Is this an issue with the linker? Does the same compiler need to be used for both R and its packages? In the case of my computer, I never explicitly asked for `g++-mp-4.5` to be used rather than the default g++ (version 4.2), so I figured R automatically detects it.

In case this is of any help, here is what my Makevars contains:

```
PKG_LIBS=`$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS) -fopenmp
PKG_CPPFLAGS=$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) -fopenmp
PKG_CFLAGS=$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS) -fopenmp
```

The `$(SHLIB_OPENMP_*FLAGS)` flags seem to be defined only on my computer; `-fopenmp` flags were explicitly added for the package to work on all the machines.

Has anyone experienced similar issues? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of details still missing in this question.

Comment: Tell me what details are missing and I will do my best to provide them.

Comment: Versions of XCode ? The .Rprofile files seem to be different as well since the libraries being referenced appear to be different.

Comment: This is my first time working on Mac OS X so I am a little lost. How does one find the .Rprofile? We are both using Xcode 3.2 but now have more recent versions of gcc (4.5, 4.6, 4.7) installed via MacPorts.

Comment: (It's possible that the MacPorts installation of required files are in directories that R is not expecting.) Files whose name begins with "." are hidden by default. I run Finder so that it shows these files. To do that type: `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`  and then you need to restart Finder.app to get the parameter to be read (but not needed later): <pt>-click-hold> on Dock-Finder-icon, choose relaunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my colleague's `~/.R/Makevars` to conform to my configs

```
LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib
CC=/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.5 -std=gnu99
CXX=/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5
CPP=/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.5 -std=gnu99 -E
CXXCPP=/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5 -E
CFLAGS=-pipe -O2 -m64
CXXFLAGS=-pipe -O2 -m64
SHLIB_CXXLD=/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5
SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS=-dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress
SHLIB_LD=/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.5 -std=gnu99
SHLIB_LDFLAGS=-dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress
```

Additionally, the `--no-multiarch` argument was used when issuing the installation command. And it now works on his computer.

The problem was because the use of openMP was hardwired (no checks) inside the code and `clang` did not support openMP at the same I asked the question.  My colleague's R was installed using the default (Xcode) compiler when we were trying to use gcc via Mac Ports.